# Eclipse- How do you enable this class option from the File menu?

Tags: eclipse

Ive searched the internet, but found nothing pertaining to my question. From the link below, go to 3:58.
The class option I'm talking about is called **"Visual Class."**

http://www.youtube.com/watch?NR=1&feature=endscreen&v=R6Mq_Fn5ZZI

You will see the user highlighting an option called "Visual Class" from File->New-> from within Eclipse. Upon searching my Eclipse program (Indigo), there is no such options. Is there any way I can access this option show on the video? Or is this an old feature that has been deprecated from newer versions of Eclipse?

Comment: Visual Editor which is a GUI editor is quite outdated (2009). The project has been archived. You can use WindowBuilder http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/646379/ more about WB http://www.rcp-vision.com/?p=67&lang=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Visual Editor in Eclipse. See more details [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/VE/Update).